# making an array go backwards for text in a text view (android)

Tags: java, android, arrays

So I am trying to make an array go backwards for flashcards

The objective is to make flashcards.  the array has both the question and the answer right after it so if I click a button it will go to the next index in the array just fine.
But when trying to go backwards it will only go back one and work, but when pressed again it will fail.  Or if I go back one, I can no longer go forward or it will fail.  Here's the code

```
// variable at the top
int i = 1;

// code that works
public void nextcard() {
    questions.setText(QuesArray[i]);// calling the

    i++;

    // checking if it hit the end. Then starting from the beginning
    if (i >= QuesArray.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
}

// code that gives me errors for going back
public void previousCard() {
    questions.setText(QuesArray[i]);// calling the

    --i;

    // checking if it hit the beginning and then starting at the end of the
    // array
    if (i <= (QuesArray.length - QuesArray.length)) {
        i = QuesArray.length;
    }
}
```

Nextcard(); and previousCard(); are called when either the next or back button is pressed.
Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here but most notably the statement:

```
i = QuesArray.length;
```

This should be:

```
i = QuesArray.length - 1;
```

This should behave as you expect:

```
// variable at the top
int i = 0;

// code that works
public void nextcard() {        
    i++;

    // checking if it hit the end. Then starting from the beginning
    if (i >= QuesArray.length) {
        i = 0;
    }

    questions.setText(QuesArray[i]);// calling the
}

// code that gives me errors for going back
public void previousCard() {
    --i;

    // checking if it hit the beginning and then starting at the end of the
    // array
    if (i < 0) {
        i = QuesArray.length - 1;
    }

    questions.setText(QuesArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that actually worked perfectly.  Now I can study lol without that bothering me.

Answer (score 0):

check the i whether it goes underflow 0

```
public void previousCard() {
    //checking if it hit the beginning and then starting at the end of the array
    if (i == 0) {
        i = QuesArray.length - 1;
    }
    else {
        --i;
    }

    questions.setText(QuesArray[i]);// calling the
}
```